# stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: linux, bash, perl

```
perl script.pl --f1="t1" --f2="t2" --f3="t4" --f4 < /home/joe/a.txt
```

script.pl

```
use Getopt::Long;
my ($f1, $f2, $f3, $f4) ;
GetOptions (
            'f1=s' => \$f1,
            'f2=s' => \$f2,
            'f3=s' => \$f3,
            'f4' => \$f4, );
if ($f1) {
    system('stty -echo');
    print "Password:";
    $pwd = <STDIN>;
    system('stty echo');
}
```

I got this error:

```
stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
Password:stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

What is this error? How do I resolve it?

Comment: The first step is to show us what the script is doing to cause that error, that is: the relevant bits of the "script.pl"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is you are reading from a redirected STDIN (because you <file.txt)

```
$ perl -e 'system("stty -echo");' </tmp/foo
stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

You should probably pass your file as a parameter to your script.

Answer (score -2):

This message is **painful**, for users and programmers. It pollutes the STDOUT, sometimes 3 times in a row.

There is **no way to suppress it**, even with messing with the `stty -echo` stuff.

The sole solution is to **redirect all the errors to** `/dev/null`

```
./myscript <<< "some stuffs" 2> /dev/null
Or similary
echo "stuffs" | ./myscript 2> /dev/null
```

Annoying, and thus throw away all potential errors, which is **not wanted at all**.

```
not wanted at all.
```